# How to see the latest version of the package in package.json?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Using **PhpStorm 2021.1.4** In `composer.json` of my project with current version of any package I see latest version of this package, but `package.json` does not show this option.

This is what I see in composer.json:

[image: ehttps://prnt.sc/26q0i2s]

But what I see in package.json:

[image: https://prnt.sc/26q0j4m]

Is it configurable somehow ?

Comment: Question is not clear enough, please consider providing detail of the subject.

Comment: Edited. Please take a look

Comment: Please post text as text here, not as links to images…

Comment: I don't get your question. The arrow points to the version constraint in your composer.json, that does not need to match the actual version that is installed, neither does it match the "latest version of this package"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Intellij Idea & WebStorm/PhpStorm you can go to package.json and hover+Cmd key (windows Ctrl key) the package name and a nice tooltip with the latest version will pop up, for example:

[image]

Comment: Such hotkeys dose not work for me. Which is name of this command ?

Comment: @mstdmstd It works, but you would need the latest **2021.3** for that. P.S. If "Show doc on hover" option is enabled it will also show that info on just a hover (you would need to hold the cursor still over the element for about 0.5sec (the default value).

Comment: I just checked that I have PhpStorm 2021.1.4, but I did not find option "Show doc on hover". Please point full path to it.

Comment: @mstdmstd "Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Editing | Show quick documentation on hover"

Comment: @mstdmstd See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2021/11/webstorm-2021-3/#new_inspection_for_updating_dependencies **P.S.** In your 2021.1 you should still be able to use `Settings | Languages and Frameworks | Node.js and NPM` to see the global and local packages (has been removed in 2021.3 in favour of package.json)